# Chain rule and the derivative of absolute value functions

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

Is it possible to use the chain rule to calculate the derivative of $|x^4|$ and $|x|^4$ in $x=0$? Does the derivative to these functions exist in $x=0$?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about the derivative of $|g(x^4)|^4$ when $x=0$?

Comment: Could you please clarify what "og" means here? Or reply to Clayton's question? Otherwise, the question is very unclear.

Comment: "og" means and. I'm norwegian and unfortunately I suddenly wrote a norwegian word. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the derivative exists since $|x^4|=x^4$.

But just first ignore the rigor. We have
$$\frac{d}{dx}|x^4|=4x^3\frac{d}{dy}|y|=4x^3sgn(y)~~~~~(y=x^4~and~y\neq0)$$
If derivative is computed at $x\neq0$, then
$$\frac{d}{dx}|x^4|=4x^3sgn(x^4)=4x^3$$
But for $x=0$, chain rule cannot be applied since $|x|$ doesn't have derivative at $x=0$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the abbreviation "sgn". What does it mean?

Comment: That means the sign of x. $sgn(x)=x/|x|$ if $|x|>0$, $sgn(0)=0$